# CF compliance - why are certain variables required if WKT defined?

Tags: netcdf, well-known-text, climate

I'm trying to make a NetCDF CF-compliant, where the `crs` variable uses a WKT string. I'm using [this compliance checker](https://github.com/ioos/compliance-checker), testing against CF 1.7. I'm getting errors that certain attributes should be defined, even though the information requested is already in the WKT string.

This seems like a bug, but in example 5.12 [in this section](https://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.8/cf-conventions.html#use-of-the-crs-well-known-text-format) of the CF 1.8 conventions, there are attributes defined that are also in the WKT string, e.g. false easting/northing, lon/lat of projection meridian/origin. Is there a reason for this? Or, does this seem like something to bring up with contributors to the CF convention, or developers of the compliance checker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use python, this may be helpful: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/build_crs_cf.html

http://cfconventions.org/cf-conventions/cf-conventions.html#use-of-the-crs-well-known-text-format

"The crs_wkt attribute is intended to act as a supplement to other single-property CF grid mapping attributes (as described in Appendix F); it is not intended to replace those attributes. If data producers omit the single-property grid mapping attributes in favour of the crs_wkt attribute, software which cannot interpret crs_wkt will be unable to use the grid_mapping information. Therefore the CRS should be described as thoroughly as possible with the single-property grid mapping attributes as well as by crs_wkt."